# How to use pick list with Pagination?

Tags: java, jsf, user-interface, richfaces

I searched for a component that can enable me to select multiple items
Then i found `rich:pickList`
Like that
[image]

*But there is a problem*
**My source list count is very large** nearly 100 000 records
So
Its not *unusable* to show all
Also not a good for a *performance* to load all without pagination

So
Any idea how to use `rich:pickList` with Pagination?
Like that
[image]
Or any suggested component that can enable me to select multiple items from huge source list?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should not be looking to use the picklist in the first place, with so many options to choose from. I won't recommend a selection component, when there are a possible 100k options to choose from. How many pages are you expecting your users to page thru to select options?

Comment: @kolossus not determined yet .. assume any number

Comment: A picklist is definitely out of the question. Usually, when there so many options to pick from, the user is expected to have *some* idea of what they want; think autocomplete. The user should type in some entry and then get suggestions. Get the user to pick from that and add to a collection. Otherwise, just go full datatable